# Internet Explorer: Unable to get property 'getItem' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, parse-platform

I have created a parse register and login, and where the JavaScript functions work and respond well in Firefox and Chrome, but does not seem to respond in internet explorer.

I am using Internet Explorer 11, and when attempting to login, the following error occurred in the developer console:

```
Unable to get property 'getItem' of undefined or null reference
```

under exception -> stack: stack

```
 "TypeError: Unable to get property 'getItem' of undefined or null reference\n   at current 
(http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.2.12.min.js:3:6125)\n   at Anonymous function 
(file:///C:/Users/test/Desktop/test/js/functions.js:6:3)\n   at d 
(https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js:27:220)\n   at Anonymous 
function (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js:29:377)\n   at m 
(https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js:6:190)\n   at sb 
(https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js:29:358)\n   at c 
(https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js:16:23)\n   at rb 
(https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js:16:226)\n   at jc 
(https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js:15:415)\n   at Anonymous 
function (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js:163:151)"
```

for the following line:

```
$scope.currentUser = Parse.User.current();
```

Below is the Parse JavaScript functions:

```
    Parse.initialize("ID", "ID");

angular.module('AuthApp', [])
.run(['$rootScope', function($scope) {
  $scope.scenario = 'Sign up';
  $scope.currentUser = Parse.User.current();

  $scope.signUp = function(form) {
    var user = new Parse.User();
    user.set("First Name", form.fname);
    user.set("Last Name", form.lname);
    user.set("password", form.password);
        user.set("email", form.email);

    user.signUp(null, {
      success: function(user) {
window.location = 'myprofile.php'
      },
      error: function(user, error) {
        alert("Unable to sign up:  " + error.code + " " + error.message);
      }
    });    
  };

  $scope.logIn = function(form) {
    Parse.User.logIn(form.lemail, form.lpassword, {
      success: function(user) {
  window.location = 'myprofile.php'
      },
      error: function(user, error) {
        alert("Unable to log in: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
      }
    });
  };

  $scope.logOut = function(form) {
window.location = 'index.html'
  };
}]);
```